# why its called using an interrupt

Tags: embedded, interrupt

in the code bellow i see the use of USART register .
Why do we need  USART1->IEN = USART_IEN_RXDATAV; and NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_RX_IRQn);
An interupt is a simething that stops the general code to execute another code.
I cant see it here.
I cant see how the operations in the code bellow are interupts?

```
void USART1_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(USART1->STATUS & (1 << 7)) {   // if RX buffer contains valid data
                      rx_char = USART1->RXDATA;       // store the data
                    }
                    if(rx_char) {                     // if we have a valid character
                      if(USART1->STATUS & (1 << 6)) { // check if TX buffer is empty
                        USART1->TXDATA = rx_char;     // echo received char
                        rx_char = 0;                  // reset temp variable
                      }
                    }


}
```

Comment: You should add a tag for whatever language this is.

Comment: "An interupt is something that stops the general code to execute another code" - You're right on that, and so close to the big picture. This function `USART1_RX_IRQHandler` **is** the interrupt handler. This is the "other code" that gets executed in response to an RX USART1 interrupt. I'm guessing that in this code example somewhere else, this function is set as the interrupt handler for that type of interrupt.

Comment: Hello , I could not find the description of NVIC_EnableIRQ and USART_IEN_RXDATAV In the API so i could read more on that.
In what section in the API link are they located?
Thanks.
https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/latest/efm32lg/group-emlib

Comment: There are functions to enable interrupts in the API, just look for them. -- But from your question and comment I think you need to learn a lot before you should try to master this. You need to read the data sheet, the programmer's manual, and similar to learn more. And you will need some tutorial...

Comment: could you please reccomend me a tutorial?